# Elasticsearch: how to update indexed scripts (search templates)

Tags: elasticsearch

How does someone update search templates that are under `.scripts` index in Elasticsearch?

In my scenario, i've created a search template and after a while I updated it, however it still produces output as in version 1.

How do I update script (indexed search template) ?
Do I need to turn something on?

`.scripts` index has refresh interval set to -1, I tried manually refreshing index - that didn't help.

Comment: What is your template and what did you change at it?

Comment: It was just a test template. I've added size parameter with default value in it. `"size" : {{size}}{{^size}}5{{/size}}"`. That's it.

Comment: In my tests, if I change that 5 to something else and `POST` again the template, it works in the query, meaning I see not 5 but 3 or whatever results.

Comment: That's what I did as well. I'll give a look at my configuration. Perhaps there's something pre-configured.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Well that's awkward. It feels like I tried everything, but nothing helped so far.

Comment: I'd wish I can help you, but I don't have much details about what you tried, the queries, how you run them and many other things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82213/discussion-between-evaldas-buinauskas-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: Could we move to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat we had, I found out that you are using ES 1.5.0. My tests with 1.6.0 were working perfectly. You still had the unknown related to `refresh_interval: -1` but that was just a red herring.

The most likely reason for this is a [bug introduced in 1.5.0, but fixed in 1.5.2](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10526).

In my tests I restarted the node and the template started to work with the updated version. Which proves that the restart (implicitly clearing the cache), made the problem go away and matched the bug description.

The solution is to upgrade and, if you are doing this, maybe consider upgrading to the latest ES version.